# MVC 4 calculations from two table models

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Using MVC 4, I have two related table from database (RATE and PAYOUT). 
Everytime i make (Create) a transaction in table "PAYCHECK", I want it to calculate totals for fields: OrdinarySalary, OvertimeSalary, HolidaySalary, etc.

I have done some calculations in my PayCheckController but its only returns a Primary Key (RateNumber) from table RATE. It does not returns other field but the primarykey.

Here is a get Method

```
    // GET

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Employee_No = new SelectList(db.EMPLOYEEs, "Employee_No", "Employee_No");
        ViewBag.RateNumber = new SelectList(db.RATES, "RateNumber", "Description");
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PAYOUT payout, RATE rate)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {  if (payout.RateNumber == rate.RateNumber)
            {

                payout.OrdinarySalary = Convert.ToInt32(payout.OrdinaryHours) * Convert.ToInt32(rate.Ord_Sal_rate);

                payout.OvertimeSalary = Convert.ToInt32(rate.Over_Sal_rate) * Convert.ToInt32(payout.OvertimeHours);

                payout.HolidaySalary = Convert.ToInt32(rate.Hol_Sal_rate) * Convert.ToInt32(payout.HolidayHours);

                payout.GrossWage = payout.OrdinarySalary+
                                   payout.OvertimeSalary +
                                   payout.HolidaySalary + 
                                   payout.BonusPay + 
                                   payout.ShiftAllowance;

                payout.ShiftAllowance = payout.GrossWage * 78 / 100;
            }
            db.PAYOUTs.Add(payout);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Employee_No = new SelectList(db.EMPLOYEEs, "Employee_No", "Employee_No", payout.Employee_No);
        ViewBag.RateNumber = new SelectList(db.RATES, "RateNumber", "Description", payout.RateNumber);
        return View(payout);
    }
```

Below is the View:

```
    @model MvcApplicationPayroll.Models.PAYOUT

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="page-header">Pay Out </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Fill in the form below to Pay An Employee &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-fw">@Html.ActionLink("Back to the List", "Index") </a>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_No, "EMPLOYEE No.")
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("Employee_No", "SELECT EMPLOYEE")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_No)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RateNumber, "Rate/Level")
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("RateNumber","SELECT LEVEL")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RateNumber)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">
                                Ordinary Hours
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrdinaryHours, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrdinaryHours)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">
                                Overtime Hours
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OvertimeHours, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OvertimeHours)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">
                                Holiday Hours
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HolidayHours, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HolidayHours)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">

                                Other Deduct
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Other_Deduct, new { @class = "form-control"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Other_Deduct)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">

                                1 Other Deduct
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Other_Deduct1, new { @class = "form-control"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Other_Deduct1)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-5">

                                2 Other Deduct
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Other_Deduct2, new { @class = "form-control"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Other_Deduct2)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                            <span class="fa fa-save fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>Save
                        </button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <a class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-fw">@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
}
```

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code - show the GET method and the view

Comment: I've added GET method and the view Stephen

Comment: You not rendering any form controls for properties of `Rate` (and nor should you because you just selecting a rate). You need to get the `Rate` from the database again based on the selected ID, and use it for your calculations

Comment: I've got it working... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've added these lines... and seem to be working

```
public ActionResult Create(PAYOUT payout, RATE ratenum)
    {


        var rate = db.RATES.First(m => m.RateNumber == ratenum.RateNumber);
```